# Eloquent relationships laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, database-relations

I have 3 tables

**categories**

- id
- name

**categories_product**

- id
- category_id
- product_id

and a product table

**products**

- id
- name

I want products based on catergori_id, how kan i do that with laravel Eloquent?

Comment: Have you already created the models?

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to query data from product table with category_id.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
Product::whereCategori_id($category)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
You mean like this?
Product::where('Categori_id', '=', $category_id)->get();
which kind of relationship should i use then? one to many?

Comment: that does the same yes. As a product belongs to a category, you should use the belongsTo relationship :)

Comment: $products = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('category_products', 'products.id', '=', 'category_products.product_id')
        ->where('category_products.category_id', '=', '1')->get(); worked :)

Comment: I get this error with your solution.  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `category_id` = 1)