# Laravel Eloquent Distinct foreach results subquerys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using suggestion in [Eloquent relationships laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920372/eloquent-relationships-laravel)

i do:

```
echo Cards::distinct('digitos')->count('digitos'); 
$digitos =  Cards::where('campanha_id',$campanha->id)->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT digitos'))->get();
foreach($digitos as $digito){
    echo $digito->digitos;
}
```

will return:

diferent digits: 48

the loop >>> 
146 - 248 - 236 - 346 - 256 - 245 - 257 - 367 - 234 - 368 - 356 - 267 - 127 - 235 - 268 - 147 - 238 - 145 - 347 - 126 - 158 - 348 - 258 - 134 - 128 - 138 - 247 - 345 - 157 - 358 - 168 - 124 - 246 - 156 - 167 - 125 - 357 - 135 - 123 - 237 - 148 - 136 - 137 - 239 - 249 - 149 - 129 - 139 -

---

in laravel eloquent mysql query:
how implement count foreach number as example:
146 (7 results) - 248 (3 results) - 236 (30 results) - etc......

directy in Eloquent query?
Thanks.

in loop insert the query, but slow.

Comment: distinct() does not accept arguments and does nothing on Eloquent Models selcting all fields because they are all distinct if not for the primary key

Comment: in this case what best way?

Comment: The best way in programming is not programming at all. In your case, edit your question and show us what you want, what you get and what you are trying. If you write a good question you will have good answers. Right now your question is a bit unclear. Please read here on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Welcome to SO.

Comment: `$your_query->get()->groupBy('digitos')`

Comment: @IGP your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [`groupBy()` Collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby)

```php
$your_query->get()->groupBy('digitos')
```